# MVVM get Validation of ContentPresenter and CancelEdits

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, cancel-button

I have built a simple TestClass for you:

following Classes:

```
public abstract class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged

public class Adult : Person

public class Child : Person
```

- Person: FirstName + LastName
- Adult: Company
- Child: School

I store this data in an `ObservableCollection<Person>` and would like to display it in my Window:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" Grid.Column="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The selected one I display in a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Adult}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="First Name:"/>
                <TextBox>
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="FirstName">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:NotEmptyRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text="Last Name:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/> <!-- Validation same as FirstName --> 
                <TextBlock Text="Company:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Company}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="First Name:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/> <!-- Validation same as above--> 
                <TextBlock Text="Last Name:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/> <!-- Validation same as above--> 
                <TextBlock Text="School:"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding School}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Now can anyone tell me how to cancel my edits (CancelCommand) or save them (SaveCommand) in correct MVVM-way.

Right now my Programm saves them when the TextBox loses the Focus and they cannot be undone.

Could anyone post me an example please?

Moreover I don't get that my input is not valid:
I tried that with:

```
private void SaveCommand_Execute()
{
    //this is the current window
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Entry is {0}valid", IsValid(this) ? "" : "not "), "Validation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}


private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
{
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) && LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>().All(IsValid);
}
```

But even if my TextBox shows the error my function tells me that the entry is valid.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Error will not get in LogicalTreeHelper. Because TextBox is inside the DataTemplate, that is visualTree.

Comment: Ok that is logic, but how should I preform it in a correct way?

Comment: I could try to acces my StackPanel of the DataTemplate but the ContentTemplate of my ContentPresenter is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want validation, you need to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` on your entities. If you want to revert changes, you need to implement `IRevertibleChangeTracking`. Both are not easy tasks, if you have never done it before.

There is also another approach to solve the Accept/Cancel issue. When you start editing a `Person`, you copy all the data to `PersonViewModel`. You will then databing to `PersonViewModel` and when user clicks save, copy data back to `Person`, when user clicks cancel, just ignore the changes.

`PersonViewModel` class is not mandatory, you could just create new instance `Person`, but `PersonViewModel` gives you more flexibility in UI logic. For example, you can have password and repeat password fields at presentation layer, but in the business entity you want to have just password.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Maybe that this is a stupid question but what's the difference between: IEditableObject and IRevertibleChangeTracking

Comment: IRevertibleChangeTracking just revert or accepts changes. IEditableObject also support BeginEdit in case, you want to handle the object differently, while editing.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution to undo the Changes:

```
public abstract class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable, IEditableObject
```

Implemented Interface Members:

```
Person _Backup = null;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        _Backup = Clone() as Person;
        HasChanges = false;
    }


    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        foreach (var Prop in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Prop.SetValue(this, Prop.GetValue(_Backup));
        }
        HasChanges = false;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        _Backup = null;
        HasChanges = false;
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
    private const string SelectedPersonPropertyName = "SelectedPerson";
    private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedPerson != null)
            {
                _SelectedPerson.EndEdit();
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.BeginEdit();
            }
            _SelectedPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedPersonPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

To realize my Validation Rules:

```
    private const string FirstNamePropertyName = "FirstName";
    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_FirstName == value)
                return;
            ValidationResult _Result = _NotEmptyRule.Validate(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            if (!_Result.IsValid)
            {
                AddError(FirstNamePropertyName, ValueIsNullOrBlank);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveError(FirstNamePropertyName, ValueIsNullOrBlank);
            }
            _FirstName = value;
            HasChanges = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged(FirstNamePropertyName);
        }
    }

    private const string ValueIsNullOrBlank = "ValueIsNullOrBlank";

    private NotEmptyRule _NotEmptyRule = new NotEmptyRule();
    private Dictionary<string, List<object>> _Errors = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
    protected void AddError(string PropertyName, object Error)
    {
        if (!_Errors.ContainsKey(PropertyName))
        {
            _Errors[PropertyName] = new List<object>();
        }
        if (!_Errors[PropertyName].Contains(Error))
        {
            _Errors[PropertyName].Add(Error);
            RaiseErrorsChanged(PropertyName);
        }
    }

    protected void RemoveError(string PropertyName, object Error)
    {
        if (_Errors.ContainsKey(PropertyName) && _Errors[PropertyName].Contains(Error))
        {
            _Errors[PropertyName].Remove(Error);
            if (_Errors[PropertyName].Count == 0)
            {
                _Errors.Remove(PropertyName);
            }
            RaiseErrorsChanged(PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseErrorsChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName) ||
            !_Errors.ContainsKey(PropertyName)) return null;
        return _Errors[PropertyName];
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return _Errors.Count > 0; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    private const string HasChangesPropertyName = "HasChanges";
    private bool _HasChanges;
    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get
        {
            return _HasChanges;
        }
        set
        {
            _HasChanges = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(HasChangesPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

The only problem I have here: I do not clone back my private fiels (just my Properties) does anyone know help here?

Comment: if you decided to copy object, wouldn't it be better to edit the copy of the person, instead of original object? In that case you don't need to revert changes when user clicks cancel. Also, other pieces of UI databount to the original object won't be affected while editing.

Comment: would you make a public property "copyedObject" and bind ui to person.copyedObject?

Comment: no. I would pass copy of the person (instead of person itself) to EditPage as a parameter

Comment: That's a good idea, but then I don't need the IEditableObject anyway?

Comment: No. Why would you need to revert changes? Of cource you need to implement accepting changes somehow.